# IOS8 iBeacon Monitoring after device reboot

Tags: ios8, ibeacon

I am developing an IOS application with iBeacon monitoring and ranging.  The app is running on an iPad with a clean install of IOS8, and there are no other applications installed.  Foreground and background monitoring with notifications are working great.  Ranging is also working great.  However, after a reboot the application never receives callbacks when it detects a beacon.  I do have the required background modes enabled.  I have local notifications added for callbacks such as didEnterRegion, didExitRegion, didDetermineState in the AppDelegate.  None of these are called after reboot, and when in the presence of an active beacon.

However, installing the same application repackaged under a different name along with the original application yields a different result.  About 4mins after reboot, I start to receive notifications from both applications.

If I remove one of the two applications, I end up with the original issue of not receiving callbacks after a reboot.  Keep in mind both are using identical code.

I have been scratching my head for a bit now, and I want to know if this behavior can be confirmed elsewhere with a fresh install of IOS with just a single iBeacon enabled application installed.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. Try repeating your tests with a known working beacon reference app like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8).  If you reproduce the issue here, it may be a hardware of OS problem.
2. Turn off the beacon before reboot, turn it back on about four minutes after reboot, then wait up to 15 minutes for a detection by your app.  Depending on the age of your iPad model, detections in the background can be slow.
3. If Locate works, but your app does not even after 15 minutes, post a simplified version of your code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: On a clean install of IOS8.  I installed just Locate.  After a reboot, waited 5mins, turned on the beacon, and waited for 30mins.  There were no notifications letting me know about entering/exiting a region.

I then installed my application with Locate.  After a reboot, waited 5mins, turned on the beacon.  I did receive notifications from both applications.

What I didn't mention in the original post was that I had tested this process with multiple beacon demos found on the web including others from radius networks.  Same results in all I could find.